# fast way of multiplication of rows of matrix with columns of another one

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two matrices and I want to multiply each column of the first one with a row of the second one to obtain a matrix, something as follows:

```
for j=1:size(A,2)
    c(:,:,j) = A(:,j)*B(:,j)'  ;
end
```

`A`and `B` have the same size.

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: Sizes of `A`, `B`, `C`?

Comment: One question per question, please. I removed your second question; feel free to post it as a new question if relevant.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett can I edit my first question as my second one?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett my second question is a general form of my first question and I think asking just a more general one is not appropriate. what can I do? ask it as a new question?

Comment: Just ask a new question. This one got closed and will not get any attention. You should refer to this one and state how your new question is different from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
C = bsxfun(@times, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(B, [3 1 2]));
```

Comment: Should be good for this! :)

Comment: Nice. Not unsurprisingly, the simple `for` loop is faster for large matrices (larger than about 200-by-200 on my system). Probably related to the cache.

Comment: @horchler Yes. It's a "pity" that ordinary loops are not as slow as they used to be. That removes part of the fun to Matlab's programming :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo The issue is that the matrix multiplications are just too fast, rendering `bsxfun(@times`...just "not too good" when compared against naive for-loops. The other operations with `bsxfun` fair comparatively better though.